# Difference between directed community indicators variational parameters in Airoldi et al 2009

Tags: graphical-model, latent-variable, social-network, variational-bayes

In the paper by [Airoldi, Blei, Fienberg, Xing, 2008](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume9/airoldi08a/airoldi08a.pdf), sometimes I see a distinction between $\phi_{p\rightarrow q}$ and $\phi_{q\leftarrow p}$ and sometimes not (the non-distinction in the generative process) when considering the asymmetric directed graphs.

Does this distinction exist or not?

In other words, in a directed network of $N$ individuals, do we have $N-1$ of  $\phi_{p\rightarrow .}$'s and $N-1$ of $\phi_{.\leftarrow p}$'s for each individual $p$?

Answer (score 2):

They are certainly distinct: Each $\phi_{p \to q}$ and $\phi_{p \leftarrow q}$ is a variational parameter corresponding to $z_{p \to q}$ and $z_{p \leftarrow q}$. These refer, respectively, to the (unobserved, latent) group membership of $p,q$ **when $p$ connects to $q$**. From the [NIPS paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3578-mixed-membership-stochastic-blockmodels.pdf) on the model:

> The indicator vector $z_{p \to q}$ denotes the specific block membership of node $p$ when it connects to node $q$, while $z_{p\leftarrow q}$ denotes
>   the specific block membership of node $q$ when it is connected from node $p$.

In other words, the ordering of the nodes in the subscript denotes the direction of the connection: $p$ before $q$ implies $p$ is connecting to $q$. The tail of the arrow faces the node whose membership is referenced.

There exist $2N^2$ of them, which you can see intuitively in Fig. 1:

[image]

Comment: In the generative process for a link between $p$ and $q$, meaning $p\rightarrow q$, the community indicators drawn are $z_{p\rightarrow q}$ and $z_{q\rightarrow p}$. In the picture however it is $z_{p\rightarrow q}$ and $z_{p\leftarrow q}$. My question is whether $z_{q\rightarrow p}$ is any different from $z_{p\leftarrow q}$

Comment: @A.Yazdiha Why don't you e-mail one of the four authors to ask?

Comment: @A.Yazdiha Ah, I see I erred in typing my arrows, see my edit. Though, the description in the monks example of the fuller is somewhat at odds with how I interpret the description quoted above, so you may wish to follow William's advice and contact one of the authors.